# How to properly make a loop with a list of URLS from a CSV file (BAT file)

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file

I need to load a list of URLs from a CSV file to a BAT file and make it go to each one of those URLs, then close it and go to the next one.

I know it is possible, but the other threads I found are too complicated and I don't know where I need to save the CSV file.

This is the code I've already written:

```
start chrome https://www.google.co.in/
timeout 5
taskkill /f /im chrome.exe
```

I need a code that goes to 500 URLs. Can you show an example of how I go to each one of those in the code? (or how I do a loop but I need the loop to include `timeout` of 5 seconds, then `taskkill` on every single loop.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please can you share the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Show us a few lines of your CSV. It's easy to loop over a file, but we need to know exactly how the CSV looks like (as CSV suggests, there is more data than just one URL per line)

Comment: The CSV looks like this: www.google.comwww.facebook.com

Comment: All of the links on the CSV are from culumn A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `CSV` looks like this (just one URL per line, nothing else):

```
www.google.com
www.facebook.com
www.stackoverflow.com
```

Then you just need a simple `for /f` loop:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (list.csv) do (
    start chrome "https:\\%%a"
    timeout 5
    taskkill /f /im chrome.exe
)
```

Comment: Where do I save the csv file?

Comment: You'd save them in the same folder as the batchfile (or give the complete path like `... in (C:\path\to\list.csv) do ....`) (just out of curiosity: what's the idea behind automatic visiting a bunch of websites and close them again?)

Comment: I need to scrape Google results for building backlinks (SEO). I tried the code, but it runs only once. How do I make it run multiple times (so it goes each time to the next link)

Comment: Do you mean, it just visits the first link or do you mean it should restart with the first one when it has visited the whole list?

Comment: It works, I did some mistake at first. Thank you very much

Comment: Yes.. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: There is a problem. I am trying to go to this link: https://www.google.com/search?q=""%2B"423"your+name+%28required%29" but it removes the " for some reason. Maybe it thinks it's a code or something?

Comment: You have to replace each `"` with `%22` in your CSV. (it's about how the browser interprets  an URL)

Comment: How can I make the loop run 3 times, then stop do something else, and continue where it stopped?

Comment: That would be a new question.