# How to add timeout to this code? It's a loop from CSV file (BAT code)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a code that opens google chrome from a CSV file. The CSV saved as comma separated, but looks like that:

```
www.google.com
www.facebook.com
www.instagram.com
```

(I'm using only column A, so it doesn't include any commas)

I want it to go to 3 links, with 3 seconds interval between each one, then task kill all the 3, and continue next.

I've tried to add a timeout after `Set /A LineNum=%%A %% 3`, and to make it like that:

```
Set /A LineNum=%%A %% 1
Timeout 5 
Set /A LineNum=%%A %% 1
Timeout 5 
Set /A LineNum=%%A %% 1
```

But it isn't opening all 3.

This is the working code with 3 seconds interval between each tab open of the chrome browser:

```
@For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=:" %%A In ('FindStr /N "^" "list.csv" 2^>NUL')Do @(
    Set /A LineNum=%%A %% 3
    Start chrome "https:\\%%B"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If !LineNum! Equ 0 (
        Timeout 5 /NoBreak
        TaskKill /F /IM chrome.exe
    )>NUL 2>&1
    EndLocal
)
```

I just need it to go to the link, wait 3 seconds, continue to the next link, wait again 3 seconds, then perform a taskkill, and continue for all of the list of 300 links.

Comment: Of course you are, but if you do not follow the advice from the links I provided it is less likely that you will receive answers, because people are not giving their time here for no appreciation, and the acceptance and voting system is the way to show your appreciation.

Comment: I am sorry. I accepted your previous answer. Thank you. Can you please help me do a 3 seconds interval between each one?

Comment: I have additionally edited your question because the code I provided to you previously had been modified to make it not work any more. Also your question above seems to be the same as [your first question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58231392), the only difference being you've changed `5` seconds to `3` seconds! If you're not capable of changing that without our help, then there's no helping you.

Comment: I have tried to add it in various places. nothing works. I need 3 seconds between each new tab. not 3 seconds between groups of 3

Comment: Let me explain again please. what the code do now: go to each raw of the CSV file, but every 3 raws, waiting 5 seconds, and performs a taskkill. what I need it to do: I need it to go to each raw of the CSV file, wait 3 seconds between each raw. not 5 seconds between 3 raws. then perform a taskkill after 3 raws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

```bat
@For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=:" %%A In ('FindStr /N "^" "list.csv" 2^>NUL')Do @(
    Set /A LineNum=%%A %% 3
    Start chrome "https:\\%%B"
    Timeout 3 /NoBreak
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If !LineNum! Equ 0 TaskKill /F /IM chrome.exe
    EndLocal)>NUL 2>&1
```